# Java Android change ListView Object according to Observable<List<Object>>

Tags: java, android, listview, retrofit, rx-java2

I am new to Java Android. I am using retrofit for restful calls and i found some minutes ago reactivex for observable objects. The goal is to update a listview "Realtime" when a value on the database changes. To be more clear: 
I have a backend with restful webservices. The app calls this services with retrofit and puts result in a listview. 
Here are my code snippets

The rest client

```
public interface SalaClientObservable {

    @GET("kingestEE_war_exploded/rest/sala/{codAtt}")
    public Observable<List<Sala>> getSale(@Path("codAtt") String codAtt);

    @GET("kingestEE_war_exploded/rest/sala/aggiungiSala/{codAtt}/{nomeSala}")
    public Observable<String> aggiungiSala(@Path("codAtt") String codAtt,@Path("nomeSala") String nomeSala);

    @GET("kingestEE_war_exploded/rest/sala/rimuoviSala/{codAtt}/{nomeSala}")
    public Observable<String> rimuoviSala(@Path("codAtt") String codAtt,@Path("nomeSala") String nomeSala);

}
```

The Activity

```
public class SceltaSala extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lista;
    TextView labelBenvenuto;

    private ListView mListView;

    private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable;

    private AdattatoreSale mAdapter;

    private LinkedList<Sala> listaSale;

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/");

    Retrofit retrofit;


    int chiamata = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scelta_sala);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        builder = builder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
        retrofit = builder.build();


         lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaSale);
         labelBenvenuto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LabelBenvenuto);

         mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
         initListView();
         loadJSON();




    }

    private void initListView() {

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaSale);

    }

    private void loadJSON() {

        SalaClientObservable requestInterface = builder
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(SalaClientObservable.class);

        mCompositeDisposable.add(requestInterface.getSale("Stefano")
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));


    }

    private void handleResponse(List<Sala> listSala) {

        listaSale = new LinkedList<>(listSala);
        Sala[] arr = new Sala[listaSale.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(Sala s : listaSale){
            arr[i] = s;
            i++;
        }
        mAdapter = new AdattatoreSale(this,R.layout.rigasala,arr);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }

    private void handleError(Throwable error) {

        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         mCompositeDisposable.clear();
    }
```

The custom adapter

```
public class AdattatoreSale extends ArrayAdapter<Sala> {

    List<Sala> nomiSale;

    int immagineInt = R.drawable.immagineprova;

    public AdattatoreSale(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, Sala[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rigasala, null);

        ImageView immagine = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.immagine);
        TextView testoRiga = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nomeSala);

        Sala s = getItem(position);
        testoRiga.setText(s.getNomeSala());

        return convertView;
    }
```

The ListView is updated only when I rotate the screen. But I think that the rotation calls (someway) the "onCreate" method of the activity, so is not the compositeDisposable that updates the values but simply the recall of the GET method. 
What is wrong in this snippet that I found online? 
Or better, is the right way to make the automatic update of the listview?

Comment: To clarify - you're trying to get your app to update when the database on your server changes?

Comment: yes, i need it and the question is not specific to the technology that i am using. I found only this approach but every approach could be helpful

Comment: Then you'll either have to poll your server periodically (which you could do with Rx) or use some sort of websockets implementation.  Either way it's out of scope of a single question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get "live" data from the DB then that's where your adapter's data needs to come from. Normally you don't need to use Rx for that and you could get away with using LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks with which you subscribe to a table in your database (but it's a little bit of a pain to set up)
However, if you want to use Rx and database in your app, you should make use of the new Android's Architecture Components, more specifically [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html), which creates a nice abstraction layer on top of DB. After setting it up you can subscribe to DB changes with a [Flowable](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757), which will emit everytime there is a change in a specific table, and with that all your service layer would have to do is save the data returned from the network request into the appropriate table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you think that Room is more comfortable I'll try it. The real problem (created by myself!!) is that the list of object that is data source of the listview is not observable (there is another list that is in observable category) so, in this case, i need to detect the event "observable changed" to fire the change object of the list. 
I'll try to restart with your approach

Comment: Ok, I saw Room but I found only sources that permits to connect the app to sqlite DB. Then the problem will be: how I can update the sqlite according to the remote DB that is queried by restful calls?